# MySql prepare statement - is it possible to parametrize column name or function name?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that I want to write a procedure allowing me to call certain function on certain column, for example:

```
call foo('min','age') -> SELECT min(age) FROM table;
```

I want my procedure to be safe from sql injection, therefore, I'm willing to use prepared statements and parametrize the input

```
SET @var = "SELECT ?(?) FROM table;"
PREPARE x FROM @var;
EXECUTE x USING a, b;
```

Where a and b are input parameters, function and column, respectively.

However, it doesnt seem to be possible - InnoDB keeps throwing an error whenever I want to execute this statement.

Is it possible to solve this this way, or I need to resort to whitelisting?

EDIT:
Full code:

```
create procedure test(in func varchar(20), in col varchar(20))
  begin
    set @f = func;
    set @c = col;
    set @sql = "select ?(?) from table;";
    prepare x from @sql;
    execute x using @f, @c;
  end;
```

calling:

```
call test('min','age');
```

Full error:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(?) from table' at line 1

Comment: Please add more context to your problem. It is currently unclear.

Comment: I am sorry for asking something that proved to be confusing, I have edited my question.

Comment: What is the error message thrown by Innodb ?? Share the complete code your are using to create the stored procedure; and also how you are calling it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have added more detail.

Comment: A work-around is to write code that "whitelists" specific function and column names. Something like: `if ($f=='min' && $c=='id') then $sql = "select min(id) from table"; ... prepare x from @sql; execute x;` The concept is to manually write sql statements, each of which you know are valid and safe, then prepare the one that matches the parameters.

Comment: .. It is also *possible* to use `concat` to construct the query. I hesitate to mention that, because `concat` should raise a red-flag in any reviewer's mind: too easy to accidentally allow `SQL injection`. [I mention, with the warning, because otherwise someone will think of it on their own, and not realize the danger.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** parametrize column/table/function name/alias. As, `PREPARE` statement only allow "values" part of the SQL query to be used as parameters. Function/Table/Column name/alias are used to determine the validity of the SQL statement; and thus cannot be changed during run-time execution. Changing it at execution time would potentially alter whether the SQL statement was valid.

You can think of it as compiling a code; hence the compiler must know all the function/class name(s) etc for creating a valid executable (yes, we can do dynamic classes, but that is *rare*). On the other hand, we can change input "values" to the program, but *generally cannot* change the operations to be done on the input data.

Also, MySQL server would consider the parameters as literals, and apply quotes around them, before using them in query execution.

Now, in your case, you can still use the function name as parameter for Stored procedure, and generate the query string using that. But you cannot use it as a parameter for the query itself.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure test(in func varchar(20), in col varchar(20))
  begin

    set @c = col;

    -- use concat function to generate the query string using func parameter
    set @sql = concat('select ', func, '(?) from table');

    -- prepare the statement
    prepare stmt from @sql;

    -- execute
    execute x using @c;

    -- don't forget to deallocate the prepared statement
    deallocate prepare stmt;
  end$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that now it is better to use typical whitelisting, as the approach shown by you is sql-injection-prone.

Comment: @LaTeXEnthusiast why do you think it is injection prone ? If you are using a function; MySQL parser would throw error if something other than a valid function is used. And regarding "values", those are anyways parametrized. Can you give an example of SQL injection possibility ? Depending on that, maybe some other solution can be figured out.

Comment: What if we used this as the func parameter:
" * from users where id=1; /* "

Comment: @LaTeXEnthusiast it will read as: `'select  * from users where id=1; /*(?) from table` Now MySQL will try to insert parametric value in it, and will not be able to do so and throw error. You can give it a try.

Comment: Note that this works for "func", but does NOT work for "col" (@c). `call test('min', 'age')` will return a string with the column name (`age`), rather than the column value (e.g. `21`). **What OP asks for cannot be done by this technique.** As you correctly say in first sentence of the answer. To avoid injection risk, prepare acts as if the query said`select min('age') from table` - given @sql = `select min(?) from table`. You **can't** get it to do `select min(age) from table`. This is by design.

Comment: Downvoted. (Though I hope this answer is kept here, as a warning.) **Circumventing safety of parameterization via use of concat risks sql injection.** In this case, the following input returns all columns (and then returns the result of the function): `call test('*, min', 'age');`  The lesson here is to NOT attempt any fancy way around limitations of parameters or prepared statements. Even experts can fool themselves into believing they have avoided risk.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this while writing a mySQL query builder plugin.  My solution was to prefix column and function names with a "?" character (the user can change the character in the plugin preferences).

The code that builds the prepared statement looks for values that begin with "?" and inserts the subsequent column/function name into the query inline instead of as prepared statement values.