# Why does my query for highest salary has a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

**Question:**

Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+------------------------+
| getNthHighestSalary(2) |
+------------------------+
| 200                    |
+------------------------+
```

**My query:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN(

    SELECT NT.Salary as CONCAT('getNthHighestSalary','(',N,')')
    FROM (SET @i := 0;
          SELECT (@i := @i + 1) as Index, Id, Salary
          FROM Employee
          ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS NT
    WHERE NT.Index = N);
END
```

**Error:**

```
Line 5: SyntaxError: near '('getNthHighestSalary','(',N,')')
    FROM (SET @i := 0;
          SELECT (@i :='
```

Comment: You cannot use function name simply by concatenating a string. You are looking to use Dynamic SQL. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Following answers may help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53144473/2469308 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147936/2469308 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53256183/2469308

Comment: What is this:  `SELECT NT.Salary as CONCAT('getNthHighestSalary','(',N,')')`?  Just overall, your `SELECT` doesn't have much to do with the syntax of a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: To answer the original question you asked, "Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.", I think you can just select the highest (MAX) value in the Salary column and where the Id is less than or equal the nth value. Who that not be a simpler solution?

Comment: Gordon Linoff Hi, that's heading of return table  "getNthHighestSalary(2)"

Comment: WebGuy Hi, the original table is not sorted by descending order. Not sure why you compare with id.

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya Thanks. How can I kill this error? Can you give a formal answer?

Comment: The question is why does it error. I think that's been answered. If you have another question, I think you should start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize the @i variable in that manner. Typically, you either initialize it before the query with that kind of `SET` statement, or within the query like:
`.... FROM Employee, (@i := 0) AS init ....`

Also, you cannot calculate a result field's alias, or any alias actually; it's not the source of your current error, and your function wouldn't return that alias anyway; but I thought it worth noting. *I am surprised it actually didn't error on that first.*

Comment: Uueerdo Thanks. Where should I change in my query? I just want to create a new index which list salary in descending order.